# is it possible to call c++ dll from media center application

Tags: c++, winforms, dll

is it possible to call c++ dll from media center application?  I just wanted to confirm before I go further since my tests have been giving me errors.  I am successfully calling the dll methods from a Winforms application.

thanks

Matt

Comment: note, I have good reason to want to use c++ as the code I wish to execute is c++.  If I could alternatively port it to c# through unmanaged code, that would be my preference but I'm unsure whether the functionality would be supported.

Comment: I have it!  Now my family can change the audio output device within windows media center using the remote control.

Answer (score 0):

It works after all.  Note to self, do not build for a 32 bit application and expect it to work on a 64 bit application.